# multiprocessing pool.map() got "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str"

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I do a multiprocessing with python's `multiprocessing.Pool` module, but got `TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str` Error:

Here is my code:

```
 def getData(qid):
     r = requests.get("http://api.xxx.com/api?qid=" + qid)
     if r.status == 200:
        DBC.save(json.loads(r.text))

 def getAnotherData(qid):
     r = requests.get("http://api.xxxx.com/anotherapi?qid=" + qid)
     if r.status == 200:
        DBC.save(json.loads(r.text))

 def getAllData(qid):
     print qid
     getData(str(qid))
     getAnotherData(str(qid))


 if __name__ == "__main__":
     pool = Pool(processes=200)
     pool.map(getAllData, range(10000, 700000))
```

After running the code for some time (not instantly), a Exception will be thrown out

```
pool.map(getAllData, range(10000, 700000))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 251, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 567, in get
    raise self._value
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

What could be wrong? Is it a bug of the `Pool` module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a worker task raises an exception, `Pool` catches it, sends it back to the parent process, and reraises the exception, but this doesn't preserve the original traceback (so you just see where it was reraised in the parent process, which isn't very helpful). At a guess, something in `DBC.save` expects a value loaded from the JSON to be an `int`, and it's actually a `str`.

If you want to see the real traceback, `import traceback` at top level, and change the top level of your worker function to:

```
def getAllData(qid):
    try:
        print qid
        getData(str(qid))
        getAnotherData(str(qid))
    except:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise
```

so you can see the real traceback in the worker, not just the neutered, mostly useless traceback in the parent.